# Error while running JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

I have a hidden input, in Jsp I set a  JSON value.
The problem is when I do `JSON.parse` in IE8.

Getting an error.

I can't use external files like  json2.js.

(I can't  pass the json value by other method to javascript )

What else can I do?

The json contains an array of key-value items, the java script filters by some criteria

Comment: What error you are getting? Where is the code?

Comment: JSON.parse should work in IE8. What is the error you are getting? Are you sure your JSON is valid? You do not share anything that could help us help you.

Comment: `JSON.parse` throws an exception if your JSON string isn't valid. Probably that's an issue.

Comment: In order to figure that out, wrap your stuff in `try/catch` block, like try `{ var foo = JSON.parse(..)  } catch(e){ .. }`

Comment: In chrome it works, fine in IE: Message: 'JSON' is undefined

Comment: Then you're using outdated IE. Basically you have 2 options here : either use `json2.js` (even if you don't want it), or craft your own parser via `eval()`

Comment: and if someone is making you craft your own parser, your project is ... a little sick.

Comment: Would be usefull to see the json you are trying to parse.

Comment: @Dominic Green, why it's important if json.parse is not supported by ie?

Comment: @yuris I think its important because if we can see the data structure and complexity we can suggest an alternative to JSON.parse

Comment: @Dominic Green, an array of key-value items